# unsupported operand type +: built in function or method and str

Tags: python, types, uppercase, capitalization

I understand what the error is saying, I just don't understand why a function used on a string won't concatenate with a string or how to go about solving that issue. The code seems straight forward to me.

Here is the simplest code I made to test this.

```
word = word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower
```

Comment: you can use function `capitalize`. `"fOOBar".capitalize() =>  'Foobar'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `()` after `.lower`:

```
word = word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower()
```